# Why is there a fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! in this code?

Tags: go

This is in reference to following code in The Go Programming Language - Chapter 8 p.238 copied below from [this](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch8/thumbnail/thumbnail_test.go) link

```
// makeThumbnails6 makes thumbnails for each file received from the channel.
// It returns the number of bytes occupied by the files it creates.
func makeThumbnails6(filenames <-chan string) int64 {
    sizes := make(chan int64)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup // number of working goroutines
    for f := range filenames {
        wg.Add(1)
        // worker
        go func(f string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            thumb, err := thumbnail.ImageFile(f)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return
            }
            info, _ := os.Stat(thumb) // OK to ignore error
            fmt.Println(info.Size())
            sizes <- info.Size()
        }(f)
    }

    // closer
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(sizes)
    }()

    var total int64
    for size := range sizes {
        total += size
    }
    return total
}
```

Why do we need to put the closer in a goroutine? Why can't below work?

```
// closer
        // go func() {
        fmt.Println("waiting for reset")
                wg.Wait()
        fmt.Println("closing sizes")
                close(sizes)
        // }()
```

If I try running above code it gives:

> waiting for reset
>   3547
>   2793
>   fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

Why is there a deadlock in above? fyi, In the method that calls `makeThumbnail6` I do close the `filenames` channel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your channel is unbuffered (you didn't specify any buffer size when make()ing the channel). This means that a write to the channel blocks until the value written is read. And you read from the channel after your call to wg.Wait(), so nothing ever gets read and all your goroutines get stuck on the blocking write.

That said, you do not need WaitGroup here. WaitGroups are good when you don't know when your goroutine is done, but you are sending results back, so you know. Here is a sample code that does a similar thing to what you are trying to do (with fake worker payload).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var procs int = 0
    filenames := []string{"file1", "file2", "file3", "file4"}
    mychan := make(chan string)
    for _, f := range filenames {
        procs += 1
        // worker
        go func(f string) {
            fmt.Printf("Worker processing %v\n", f)
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            mychan <- f
        }(f)
    }

    for i := 0; i < procs; i++ {
        select {
        case msg := <-mychan:
            fmt.Printf("got %v from worker channel\n", msg)
        }
    }
}
```

Test it in the playground here https://play.golang.org/p/RtMkYbAqtGO

Comment: Ah nice! Yes when I add a buffer like `sizes := make(chan int64, 10)` then the code works. Thanks Mad!

Comment: Eh... it will only work if your number of payloads is less than 10. This is fragile. I highly recommend you go with the non-blocking reads the way my posted code sample does.

Comment: Yes I understand that but it helped me understand why there was a deadlock. Agree that in practice I would use the code you shared or the one in the book :)

Answer (score 1):

Although it's been a while since the question was raised, I encountered the same issue. Initially my main looked like the following:

```
func main() {
   filenames := make(chan string, len(os.Args))
   for _, f := range os.Args[1:] {
       filenames <- f
   }
   sizes := makeThumbnails6(filenames)
   close(filenames)
   log.Println("Total size: ", sizes)}
```

This version deadlocks as the call `range filenames` in `makeThumbnails6` is synchronous, thus `close(filenames)` in main was never called. The channel in `makeThumbnails6` is unbuffered so goroutines block when trying to send back the size.

The solution was to move `close(filenames)` before making the function call in main.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure how to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I would like to share my understanding of this good question.

The reason the closer function is in a goroutine is because it would cause a dependency flaw otherwise.

How?

wg.Wait() will block until the relevant goroutines return(after calling wg.Done()).

These routines can ONLY return when the sizes channel is “drained” by a receiver.

The code that “drains” sizes - and thus frees up the goroutines - is the “for” loop that receives the information from sizes.  It comes AFTER the closer function.

That means it would prevent the code that it depends on from actually executing and wait forever.

Answer (score -1):

The code is wrong. In short, the channel `sizes` is unbuffered. To fix it, we need to use a buffered channel with enough capacity when creating `sizes`. One-liner fix is enough, as shown. Here I just made a simple assumption that 1024 is big enough.

```
func makeThumbnails6(filenames chan string) int64 {
    sizes := make(chan int64, 1024)    // CHANGE 
    var wg sync.WaitGroup // number of working goroutines
    for f := range filenames {
        wg.Add(1)
        // worker
        go func(f string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            thumb, err := thumbnail.ImageFile(f)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return
            }
            info, _ := os.Stat(thumb) // OK to ignore error
            fmt.Println(info.Size())
            sizes <- info.Size()
        }(f)
    }

    // closer
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(sizes)
    }()

    var total int64
    for size := range sizes {
        total += size
    }
    return total
}
```